# How to detect airplane mode especially in jelly beam?

Tags: android

The bellow code to detect airplane mode not works in jelly beam version.

```
    // Check for Airplane Mode
    boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0) == 1;

if (isEnabled) {
// toggle airplane mode
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent = new Intent(                 Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Please share your suggestion for my doubt. Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you posted does not only try to detect airplane mode. Rather, it tries to switch it on if it is switched off. It would be nice if you provided us with the information which part is specifically not working for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Is Code Snippet is for below JB

```
    /**
* Gets the state of Airplane Mode.
* 
* @param context
* @return true if enabled.
*/
private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

   return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

}
```

In **Jelly Bean 4.2**, this setting has moved to `Settings.Global`

Comment: @Usman-how can we alter the above code to work in jelly bean version?

Comment: WITH JB replace ` Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0`
with this ` Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0`  and it will work fine

Comment: Jellybean 4.2 is api 17 or `Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLYBEAN_MR2`

Answer (score 1):

In jellybean, AIRPLANE Mode setting values are moved to global table.

And in SDK documentation, global table cannot be written by application.

> Applications can read these but are not allowed to write; like the "Secure" settings, these are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html for details.