# detect if sim card is ready in android

Tags: android

i use the following snippet to check if sim card is ready. the code works fine, however, it returns "SIM_STATE_READY" even if Airplane mode is on.

```
private void detectSimState() {
    TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
    switch (simState) {
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "SIM_STATE_ABSENT",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        // do something
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        // do something
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
        Toast toast11 = Toast.makeText(this, "SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast11.show();
        // do something
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
        Toast toast111 = Toast.makeText(this, "SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast111.show();
        // do something
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
        Toast toast1111 = Toast.makeText(this, "SIM_STATE_READY",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1111.show();
        // do something
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast2.show();
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

so how do i fix this? i believe there are two possible solutions-

1. check if airplane mode is on/off

this would probably fail to work on every android version

2. get sim radio state

how do i do that?

also, [cellSignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength.html) was added in APi 17 , so that is definitely not my cup of tea

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why airplane mode checking would be a problem. Do something like this:

```
if(SIM_STATE_READY){

if(isAirplaneModeOn()){

//Sim is ready, but will give error. Handle exception here.

}

}
```

Simply implement like this. Here are two ways you can do it:

1. Using Settings.System class:

   ```
   private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
      return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

      }
   ```
2. Using BroadCast reciever:

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: @Felicia You have to import it. Mouse over and press alt + enter

Comment: @Felicia then try the other option I have you by registering a broadcast reciever

Comment: @Felicia yeah, from the on receive method just do whatever you would do to handle the exception you were getting earlier

Comment: this code will be triggered on onboot and also on sim status change event

Comment: after that it will check for airplane mode

Comment: and you were incorrect as after jellybean, "system" was moved to "global"

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780241/how-to-detect-airplane-mode-especially-in-jelly-beam