# How to detect signal strength in Android?

Tags: android

I want to send SMS when the signal strength is above 5 (I believe that is the minimum signal required to send an SMS). however, i want a reliable method to check this, so checking signal strength seems to be the best bet as it would also cover airplane mode.

An important constraint is that [CellSignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength.html) was added in API level 17, and need my code to work on API level 8 and above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing - [SignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) in android.telephony.SignalStrenght

The class contains methods to get various network strenght for example:
`getGsmSignalStrength()` which gives you data in range 0-31 31 (99 is invalid)
For **CDMA** there are other methods like getCdmaDbm() which gives you values in dBm so you should convert them to your scale.
[EDIT]Example of use

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

final PhoneStateListener mListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
 @Override
 public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength sStrength) {
  //get your signals data
 }
};

// Register the listener for the telephony manager
telephonyManager.listen(mListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

Comment: also how do i detect if it is GSM or CDMA?

Comment: very easy - just read the docs(link in my answer) :) `isGsm()` :D

Comment: the problem is, radio still receives signal regardless of if there is sim inserted

Comment: this is going to be a long solution, (yeah i know telephonymanager can detect sim card) can you rather tell me how to detect airplane mode in all api levels? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376475/detect-if-sim-card-is-ready-in-android

Comment: i have tried that already but it says "system" cannot be resolved as a variable

Comment: Check if you reference android.provider.Settings.System not other class